# how to perform loopback test on eth0 and eth1 of a llinux machine using udp

Tags: linux

I have a linux machine with two network interface cards eth0 and eth1. I want to write a **bash** script for sending udp packets from eth0 to eth1 and vice versa. I also want to capture this communication using wireshark. Can anybody help me to write this script. Please help me. Your quick reply will be very appreciable.

Comment: Please reply ... I am very new to networking

Answer (score 0):

You can not send datagrams from one interface to another, unless they are cross-connected somehow.

There is an option for UDP multicast to receive sent UDP datagrams on the loopback (127.0.0.1) interface, but not sure if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes i am trying with the cross-over cable only. And i want to send some strings like "who are you" from eth0 to eth1 of the same pc i.e loopback test using udp protocol. But i am not getting how to tell that eth0 will be used as a udp sender and eth0 as a udp receiver

Comment: I am expecting some lines of code to configure eth0 and eth1 and the  way of sending and receiving the data in above format.

Comment: I believe that the kernel will avoid sending data over the actual physical network when the destination is an interface on the same host. The data is just copied over to the target interface without going over the network...